# Remove object from an Array of Objects using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of objects which have the links of several Operator of Flowchart.I want to remove a Specific Object from that Array

```
var link_id= $(this).siblings('g').attr('data-link_id'); // this give me index of object
$($("#LDIProjectComponents").data('flowchartFlowchart').data.links) // Gives me Array of object
```

Now I want to remove "link_id" indexed object

Comment: Check the updated answer it works

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

```
var link_id= $(this).siblings('g').attr('data-link_id'); // this give me index of object
var objArray = $($("#LDIProjectComponents").data('flowchartFlowchart').data.links) // Gives me Array of object
objArray.splice(link_id, 1);
```

Make use of the javascript `splice()` function that will remove the object with index `link_id` from array `objArray`

Comment: Splice or Slice?

Comment: use splice. Will do for you. That was a typo in the answer. This surely works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use plain JavaScript? I would suggest using the the [**.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on arrays:

```
var objs = $($("#LDIProjectComponents").data('flowchartFlowchart').data.links);

obj.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.checkProp === withSomeValue;
}
```

It should return a new array of elements which match the condition in the function given as the first param.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following code

```
 delete  $("#LDIProjectComponents").data('flowchartFlowchart').data.links[link_id]
```